# Elegant buttons in spritekit

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm looking for an elegant solution to create a button in spritekit which turns grayish when touched and goes back to normal when you drag your finger out. I have tried a method which uses touchesBegan, touchesMoved, and touchesEnded however that requires me to call each button individually and by name. I was wondering if there was a different solution which doesn't require me to individually call each node. Thank you.

Comment: Please, don't talk _about_ your code. _Show_ your code.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass  SKSpriteNode.
SkNode conforms to UIResponder.

In your subclass set userInteractionEnabled=true

Handle all your touches in the subclass.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Is there a step by step guide on this, as I'm not sure how to make SkNode respond to UIResponder.

Comment: a responder implements the touchesBegan(_:with:), touchesMoved(_:with:), touchesEnded(_:with:), and touchesCancelled(_:with:) methods. Just subclass SKSpriteNode and override those methods in the subclass.

Comment: I've written a class but it doesn't seem to work, not sure what I'm doing wrong: class SKButton : SKSpriteNode {
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.alpha = 0.5
    }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.alpha = 1.0
    }
}

Comment: did you set userInteractionEnabled to true in the subclass?

Comment: I used this line but it didn't work: override var isUserInteractionEnabled: Bool; what's the line I should be inserting?

Comment: In the init of the subclass:  call super.init and then self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

Comment: import SpriteKit
class ButtonNode: SKSpriteNode {
    
    init(imageNamed: String, size:CGSize) {
        super.init(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: imageNamed), color: SKColor.clear, size: size)
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        //your code here
    }
    }